# Source files are not open while Visual Studio editor says the inverse

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

ok, let me give you an example of what problem i'm currently facing in my Visual Studio 2013.

1. I open my solution (MVC 4).
2. I double-click on a source file in the solution explorer and I put a break point somewhere in the code.
3. I run the debugger and I navigate in my web application till the visual studio stops on my breakpoint.
4. I press F5 to continue.
   remark: the VS editor has closed my source file where the break point resides.
5. I press "stop debugging" and I double click on the source file in my solution explorer to open it.
   => nothing happens, the source file is not displayed!
6. I decide to start again the debugger and make the necessary navigation in my app in order to reach the break point.
   => this time, a tabbed window is displayed (Tab title=source not found). 
   It invites me to find my source file.
   The functionality to "Browse and find" the file does not work neither.

Now, if i want to be able to display my source file again, i must go to the Visual Studio menu -> Window -> Close all documents.
After that, a double-click on the source file in the solution explorer opens and displays the source file

remark: In this menu Window option, i can see that my source file is listed in the opened documents(?!). 
    So it means that, for the editor, the document is displayed correctly.

Somebody knows what is happening?

I tried to re-install Visual Studio and all updates (Update 4)... but nothing has changed.

Thank you.
Fred

Comment: Do you have extensions installed?  Which ones?

Comment: Not specially. The only extensions in my VS were installed during the installation.e.g. NuGet package Manager for VS2013, Application Insights Tool for Visual Studio, Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools,...